# Find strings in text and if matched place into a different text with different name

Tags: c#, replace, richtextbox, match, concatenation

I have a RichTextBox that contains:

```
CAP-00128G  0402C
CAP-00128G  0402C
CAP-00129G  TANT3715
CAP-00129G  TANT3715
CAP-00129G  TANT3715
CAP-00129G  TANT3715
CAP-00130G  12BGA_1.5
CAP-00151G  ABC
IND-00007G  0402C
RES-00455G  0402R
RES-00455G  0402R
RES-00455G  0402R
```

I would like to insert the ***2nd column*** value into the **first set of quotation marks** in a file that looks like this *(accounting for running into the same value in the second set of quotations, ie, CAP-22128G, CAP-00129G, etc.)* :

```
( 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "" "CAP-00128G" "" 2 0 0 0 0 0 ) 
( 2 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "" "CAP-00129G" "" 4 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 3 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "" "CAP-00130G" "" 1 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 4 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "" "CAP-00151G" "" 1 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 5 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "" "IND-00007G" "" 1 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 6 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "" "RES-00455G" "" 3 0 0 0 0 0 )
```

***SO*** the final text would look like this after matching the values from the strings in the first file to their proper corresponding strings and making sure that the ***2nd set of quotation marks*** matches the ***2nd column*** in the first file. **Also, if the RTB contains the values "TANT3715" or "ABC" I would like to insert a blank line (before) and still increment the counter.**:

```
( 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "0402C" "CAP-00128G" "" 2 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 2 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 3 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "TANT3715" "CAP-00129G" "" 4 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 4 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "12BGA_1.5" "CAP-00130G" "" 1 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 5 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "" "" "" 0 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 6 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "ABC" "CAP-00151G" "" 1 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 7 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "0402C" "IND-00007G" "" 1 0 0 0 0 0 )
( 8 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 "0402R" "RES-00455G" "" 3 0 0 0 0 0 )
```

Here is the code that prints out the file:

```
var part1 = lookup.Select(
    (x, i) => 
    string.Format(@"( {0} 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 """" ""{1}"" """" {2} 0 0 0 0 0 )",
    i + 1, x.Key, x.Count()));
```

So my question is:

- Can someone help me find the value that matches the **1st column value** in the RichTextBox to the line that contains that particular value, and then insert the **2nd column value** in the RTB into the quotation marks before the match? I know this may be confusing so let me know if I need to clarify please. :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your input to a dictionary:

```
var input = "CAP-00128G  0402C\r\nCAP-00128G  0402C\r\n...";

var dict = input.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" })
                .Select(row => row.Split(new string[] { "  " }))
                .ToDictionary(cols => cols[0], cols => cols[1]);
```

and then get the value for each key from the dictionary:

```
var part1 = lookup.Select(
    (x, i) => 
    string.Format(@"( {0} 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ""{3}"" ""{1}"" """" {2} 0 0 0 0 0 )",
    i + 1, x.Key, x.Count(), dict[x.Key]));
```

---

Is `lookup` the result of grouping the input?

```
var input = "CAP-00128G  0402C\r\nCAP-00128G  0402C\r\n...";

var lookup = input.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" })
                  .Select(row => row.Split(new string[] { "  " }))
                  .GroupBy(cols => cols[0], cols => cols[1]);
```

Then you can do simply this:

```
var part1 = lookup.Select(
    (x, i) => 
    string.Format(@"( {0} 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ""{3}"" ""{1}"" """" {2} 0 0 0 0 0 )",
    i + 1, x.Key, x.Count(), x.First()));
```

Comment: Sorry this has taken me awhile to get back to you. I have been having internet problems. The `lookup` looks like this: `var lookup = (from line in listLines group line by line[1]).ToArray();`. And the `input` will not be a variable but rather taken from a listBox. So.. something like this: `foreach (var item in placementOneListBox.Items) { partList.Add(item + "\n"); }`